# Unityでディスプレイスマッピングを使うとしたら・・？

Tags: javascript, c#, unity3d

少し気になった程度の事ですが質問させて下さい。

Unityでディスプレイスマッピングを使う場合はどの様な形で実装しているのでしょうか？１例の概略といった所でも良いのですが分かる方が居らっしゃいましたらお教え頂けませんでしょうか

特に気になっている所はディスプレイスマップのアニメーションです。
イメージとしてはマップをアニメーションさせて波のような動きを作る等です。

Answer (score 1):

Shader Forgeを使ってシェーダーを作成することで、Planeのジオメトリをディスプレイスメントで波を打つように変化させることができます。このサンプル例は、DX11/Windows専用です。
[image: DX11 Displacement Samples]